# Unit tests with FluentValidation. How to mock ValidationResult

Tags: unit-testing, xunit, fluentvalidation, autofixture, nsubstitute

I'm using TDD approach with xUnit 2, NSubstitute, AutoFixture, FluentAssertions for my unit tests.

I want test my service method which using FluentValidation.

Simple example:

Validator:

```cs
RuleSet("Nulls", () =>
        {
            RuleFor(viewModel => viewModel).NotNull();
        });
```

My service(under test):

```cs
if(Validate(viewModel, "Nulls"))
//....
private bool Validate(AddMerchantViewModel viewModel, string option)
{
    var result = _merchantValidator.Validate(viewModel, ruleSet: options);
    return result.IsValid;
}
```

And my unit test:

I don't know how to mock the `merchantValidator.Validate` result.

```cs
[Theory, AutoNSubstituteData]
public void Add_ViewModelAsNull_ShouldThrowArgumentNullException(
    AbstractValidator<AddMerchantViewModel> merchValidator,
    MerchantsService service)
{
    // Arrange


    //here I don't know how to mock result of Validate. It is always null.
    merchantValidator.Validate(Arg.Any<AddMerchantViewModel>(), ruleSet: Arg.Any<string>()).Return(new ValidationResult()); 



    // Act
    Action action = () => service.Add(null);

    // Assert
    action.ShouldThrow<ArgumentNullException>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default AutoFixture creates a new instance of a type every time it's requested. In this particular case the `AbstractValidator<AddMerchantViewModel>` type is instantiated twice - as the `merchValidator` parameter and as a dependency of the `MerchantsService` class.

As a result the configured *validator* is not used by the *service*. In order to fix that you should decorate the `merchValidator` parameter with the `[Frozen]` attribute so that the same instance of the `AbstractValidator<AddMerchantViewModel>` type is always returned by AF:

```
[Theory, AutoNSubstituteData]
public void Add_ViewModelAsNull_ShouldThrowArgumentNullException(
    [Frozen]AbstractValidator<AddMerchantViewModel> merchValidator,
    MerchantsService service)
// ...
```

More info abot the `[Frozen]` attribute can be found [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/08/AutoDataTheorieswithAutoFixture/).

Answer (score 0):

The [FluentValidation documentation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/testing.html#Mocking) explicitly urges **against** mocking validators.
They instead suggest using an `InlineValidator` for stubbing purposes.

This would be configured by creating the SUT within your `[Fact]` or `[Theory]` and explicitly injecting the service dependencies like so:

```
[Theory, AutoNSubstituteData]
public void Add_ViewModelAsNull_ShouldThrow(object[] merchantsServiceCtorArgs)
{
     var stubValidator = new InlineValidator<AddMerchantViewModel>();
     stubValidator.RuleFor(vm => vm).NotNull();

     var sut = new MerchantsService(stubValidator, ..merchantsServiceCtorArgs);

     Assert.ShouldThrow<ArgumentNullException>(() => sut.Add(null));
}
```